# TypeScript generics are not working for Record?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this `keyBy` function:

```js
export function keyBy<T>(items: T[] | undefined, extractId: (item: T) => number): Record<number, T> {
  const obj: Record<number, T> = {};

  if (items) {
    items.forEach(item => {
      const id = extractId(item);
      obj[id] = item;
    });
  }

  return obj;
}
```

It can be used to turn an array of objects into a dictionary of these objects, keyed by whatever you want. For example:

```js
const users = [user1, user2, ...]l
const usersById = keyBy(users, u => u.id);
```

Now I want to change this function to not only work with numeric keys like ids, but also with strings:

```js
export function keyBy<Key extends string | number, T>(items: T[] | undefined, extractId: (item: T) => Key): Record<Key, T> {
  const obj: Record<Key, T> = {};

  if (items) {
    items.forEach(item => {
      const id = extractId(item);
      obj[id] = item;
    });
  }

  return obj;
}
```

This gives the error `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Record<Key, T>'. ts(2322)`. Why is this not working?

I think the problem is that now every `id` can be either a string or a number, whereas what I want is that all ids are either a string or a number, but of course they are all the same type.

Comment: moving Key into a own definition, resolve the problem. `type Key = string | number`. But I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assign an empty object to a `Record` with enumerable keys:

> Note: I am not sure it is called "enumerable".
> However, in this post, "enumerable" means all value are known like `"a" | "b"` or `1 | 2 | 3`, and `string` or `number` is not "enumerable"

```
const obj1: Record<"id", number> = {}
// Property 'id' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Record<"id", number>'.

const obj2: Record<string, number> = {}
// OK
```

In your `keyBy` function, it is possible to pass enumerable into `Key` generic parameter, and that cause the empty object assignment issue.

The most simple way is just use `as` keyword to convert it to what you want:

```
const obj = {} as Record<Key, T>;
```